# ActivityIndicator not shown in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
///ActivityIndicator defined in xmal 

 <ActivityIndicator x:Name="popupView"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Color="DarkBlue"  IsRunning="True" IsVisible="false" IsEnabled="True" />
```

in my c# code :

```
 popupView.IsVisible = true;

for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataGrid.Children.Add(new Label
                    {
                        Text = item[i].Value,
                        TextTransform = TextTransform.None,
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        Padding = 1,
                        WidthRequest = 200,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray

                    }, i, j + 1);
                }

 popupView.IsVisible = false;
```

> ActivityIndicator is not shown. What should I do?

Comment: There's nothing in that for loop that causes your code to wait, so your code sets IsVisible, does a bunch of stuff, then sets IsVisible false - BEFORE UI has a chance to show anything. Is this a test, before writing your real code?

Comment: Try to add `await Task.Delay(100);` after set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see the activity indicator, there needs to be a delay somewhere.

Presumably this is a test you are doing, and your "real" code will be something that "takes enough time" to see the activity indicator.

Here is an approach that works. With "Sleep" simulating your code that takes time.

xaml:

```
<!-- give appropriate name to your indicator. "popupView" sounds like a different type of element. -->
<!-- Use "IsRunning" to control visibility of ActivityIndicator, not "IsVisible". -->
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="indicator" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Color="DarkBlue" />
```

cs:

```
// Use "IsRunning" to control visibility of ActivityIndicator.
indicator.IsRunning = true;

Task.Run( () =>
{
    // This code runs on background thread.
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
    {
        // Simulate an operation that takes time.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        ...
    }

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
    {
        // This code runs on MainThread.
        indicator.IsRunning = false;
    });
});
```

Note the comments indicating what code runs on background thread, what code runs on MainThread.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code,I made a simple demo, and it works properly.

You can refer to the following code:

MainPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="popupView"  VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"   IsRunning="True" IsEnabled="True"  IsVisible="false"   Color="Red"      />

    <Grid x:Name="dataGrid" ></Grid>

    <Button Text="test" Clicked="Button_Clicked"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="50"/>
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        popupView.IsVisible = true;


        Task.Run(() => {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                int j = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                {

                    dataGrid.Children.Add(new Label
                    {
                        Text = "test:" + i,
                        TextTransform = TextTransform.None,
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        Padding = 1,
                        WidthRequest = 200,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray

                    }, i, j + 1);

                    j = 0;
                }

                popupView.IsVisible = false;
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code inside Main Thread.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    { popupView.IsVisible = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataGrid.Children.Add(new Label
                    {
                        Text = item[i].Value,
                        TextTransform = TextTransform.None,
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        Padding = 1,
                        WidthRequest = 200,
                        BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray

                    }, i, j + 1);
                }

 popupView.IsVisible = false;
     });
```